# Oauth2 : how and where to store client id and secret

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have an authorization server and my client is an angular app.I'm not a third party app.
I used this symfony bundle https://github.com/trikoder/oauth2-bundle
I'm using grant type `password`.

`{  "grant_type":"password", "client_id":"myclientid", "username":"john@doe.com", "password":"foo", "client_secret":"3d4a940.....3c1ea38b5"  }`  
And the response is :

`{ "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 60, "access_token": "eyJ0eXAi....nK0Ag", "refresh_token": "def50200dfce4da3....fdc689e5" }`

The `access_token` is only valid for 1 min, afterward the client need to use the refresh token to be able to talk to my api :

`{ "grant_type":"refresh_token", "client_id":"myclientid", "client_secret":"3d4a940.....3c1ea38b5" "refresh_token": "def50200dfce4da3....fdc689e5" }` 
`client_id` and  `client_secret` are stored in a table.

My question is :
Is it safe/recommended to store the `client_id` and the `client_secret` in the local storage of the front angular app ? Because it basically represents the user credentials and if some one steal them they would have access to the api. But without them the client can't send request to the api.
I crawled the web but I can't find a real answer, even on the oauth 2 documentation

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few points here:

- Your angular app should use the authorization code flow + open id connect
- Consider using a more standard authorization server and more standard access token lifetimes
- Session storage has fewer issues around Safari / Firefox and SPA restarts
- Whether to use session storage for tokens depends on data sensitivity + risk analysis
- Consider that the session time for which access tokens are valid sometimes maps to a user consent

I have a write-up, which is based around trade offs between usability and security: https://authguidance.com/2019/09/08/ui-token-management/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed, authorization code is recommended for me, I've just figured it out (`implicit` grant type is not recommended).
For the token life, I choosed 60 secs for testing.
About Open id, my main 'issue' is that I want the user to be able to connect to the server with his own credentials, and not to use facebook, instagram etc. I will allow that, but personnaly when I have the choice, I rather prefer create an account other than using my social network credential. Or maybe we can set up a personnal OpenId provider ? 
I'm going to read your website, thanks

Comment: @gary - thanks for the answer but please can you answer the the question asked:
```My question is : Is it safe/recommended to store the client_id and the client_secret in the local storage of the front angular app ? ```